# Using FullCalendar with Angular 8, the events in dayGridMonth do not have an end value unlike timeGridWeek

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to display the end time for the event on the dayGridMonth view, however when accessing the object of eventTimeFormat, there is no value for the key 'end', unlike that of the timeGridWeek view.

How do I get FullCalendar to populate the end key with a value in the dayGridMonth view?

For dayGridMonthView

```
{
  "date": {
    "marker": "2019-09-20T10:30:00.000Z",
    "timeZoneOffset": 480,
    "array": [
      2019,
      8,
      20,
      10,
      30,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 20,
    "hour": 10,
    "minute": 30,
    "second": 0,
    "millisecond": 0
  },
  "start": {
    "marker": "2019-09-20T10:30:00.000Z",
    "timeZoneOffset": 480,
    "array": [
      2019,
      8,
      20,
      10,
      30,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 20,
    "hour": 10,
    "minute": 30,
    "second": 0,
    "millisecond": 0
  },
  "end": null,
  "timeZone": "local",
  "localeCodes": [
    "en"
  ]
}
```

For timeGridWeek

```
{
  "date": {
    "marker": "2019-09-16T10:00:00.000Z",
    "timeZoneOffset": 480,
    "array": [
      2019,
      8,
      16,
      10,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 16,
    "hour": 10,
    "minute": 0,
    "second": 0,
    "millisecond": 0
  },
  "start": {
    "marker": "2019-09-16T10:00:00.000Z",
    "timeZoneOffset": 480,
    "array": [
      2019,
      8,
      16,
      10,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 16,
    "hour": 10,
    "minute": 0,
    "second": 0,
    "millisecond": 0
  },
  "end": {
    "marker": "2019-09-16T15:00:00.000Z",
    "timeZoneOffset": 480,
    "array": [
      2019,
      8,
      16,
      15,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 16,
    "hour": 15,
    "minute": 0,
    "second": 0,
    "millisecond": 0
  },
  "timeZone": "local",
  "localeCodes": [
    "en"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the end time of an event in the dayGrid (i.e. "month") view, then you can simple set the [displayEventEnd](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventEnd) option to true:

```
displayEventEnd: true
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBWQOMR?&editable=true&editors=001

(N.B. It's unclear how `eventTimeFormat` is related to your requirement, or how you got the output above, because [eventTimeFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat) is an option you pass into fullCalendar when you set it up, to tell it how you want an individual date/time to be displayed (note **how** you want it displayed, not **whether** you want it displayed). It's not a value you would normally want to access at any other time. Since you provided no code, it's unclear in any case how, where or when you accessed that data. Either way, it doesn't help you achieve your goal.)

Comment: I am using eventTimeFormat to change the display of the time, and I accessed the data I obtained through console. I assumed that the values would be populated in the event data, just not displayed, so I was inspecting the json object for clues.

Comment: @Zetsukaze yes I realise you're seeing it in the console, but what I meant was where in the code you're running the command to log, and exactly what it is that you're logging. Because if you simply log the value of the "eventTimeFormat" option, you don't see anything like the output you've put in the question. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxKQWrG . That makes me think you're actually talking about something else but giving it the wrong name. In future, always add the exact code you're using to create the output you're talking about. Then everyone can be 100% clear about what you mean.